# Retrieve log file from distant server with FileBeat

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am currently using 4 servers, they have some log files I want to analyse. I want to use Logstash and Elasticsearch for that, and maybe filebeat too.
I have made some tests, getting the files from the servers (manually) and analyzing them with Logstash (input => file). What I want to do is to configure FileBeat to get the log files as input (from the 4 servers). 
So my question is, is it possible to make Filebeat get those files automatically as input?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install filebeat and logstash on the 4 servers (let called them server1, server2, server3 and server4) then you can install elasticsearch on one server (say server2).

You will then have to configure filebeat as follows

For server1

```
filebeat.prospectors:

- paths:
    - /path/to/log/*.*

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["server1Ip:5044"]
```

For server2

```
filebeat.prospectors:

- paths:
    - /path/to/log/*.*

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["server2Ip:5044"]
```

etc...

Used this configuration for all the 4 servers on which logstash is installed.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
 }
}
 output {
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "server2Ip:9200" ]
    index => "indexName"
 }
}
```

For elasticsearch, you will only have to set the `network.host`

```
network.host: server2Ip
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So i guess that if I wanted to install Filebeat only in one server, maybe I should write a script that gets the files from the other servers. Anyways, thanks a lot!